# Viability of Toxoplasmosis oocysts on dry smooth surfaces

Tags: parasitology, infectious-diseases

This is a weird question. My wife is terrified of contracting toxoplasmosis during pregnancy and I was hoping I could get an expert opinion here to potentially make her feel better.

She recently took the toxoplasmosis test and it came back negative. The next day, we cleaned the house. We have four cats, all indoors, who have intermittently gotten into the trash and licked containers containing raw meat or eaten raw meat that we had bought from the store. We also live in the city, no rats or rodents that they could find and kill. We keep our house fairly clean. There was a smear of dried cat poop hiding under a rug on our tile floor that I cleaned that has to be at least 5-6 months old. I had to really pick at it after spraying it to get it up. She's worried that because she handled the towel I used to clean it up with that she's potentially exposed herself to infection.

How likely is it that old, dried cat poop like that could still harbor viable oocysts? Assuming that it was infected in the first place. Do they dry out and inactivate if they're not exposed to moisture?

Thanks!